# По нажатию на форму вызвать 2 процедуры

Tags: delphi, canvas

Нужно по нажатию на форму вызывать 2 процедуры. Одна отрисовывает рисунок, вторая его двигает вниз по вертикали. Вторая процедура(Timer1Timer) почему то не вызывается. В чем ошибка?

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12 : Integer;
  y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12 : Integer;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
x1:= 20; y1:= 20;
x2:=50; y2:=50;
x3:=15; y3:= 40;
x4:=30; y4:=55;
x5:= 51; y5:= 25;
x6:=60; y6:=40;
x7:=40; y7:= 37;
x8:=60; y8:=57;
x9:= 60; y9:= 43;
x10:=60; y10:=52;
x11:=70; y11:= 52;
x12:=60; y12:=43;

Canvas.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
Canvas.Ellipse(x3, y3, x4, y4);
Canvas.Rectangle(x5, y5, x6, y6);
Canvas.Ellipse(x7, y7, x8, y8);
Canvas.Moveto(x9,y9);
Canvas.Lineto(x10,y10);
Canvas.Lineto(x11,y11);
Canvas.Lineto(x12,y12);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Pen.Color:=Form1.Color;
  Canvas.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
Canvas.Ellipse(x3, y3, x4, y4);
Canvas.Rectangle(x5, y5, x6, y6);
Canvas.Ellipse(x7, y7, x8, y8);
Canvas.Moveto(x9,y9);
Canvas.Lineto(x10,y10);
Canvas.Lineto(x11,y11);
Canvas.Lineto(x12,y12);

    x1:=X1; y1:=y1+1;
    X2:=X2; y2:=y2+1;
    X3:=X3; y3:=y3+1;
    X4:=X4; y4:=y4+1;
    x5:=X5; y5:=y5+1;
    X6:=X6; y6:=y6+1;
    X7:=X7; y7:=y7+1;
    X8:=X8; y8:=y8+1;
    x9:=X9; y9:=y9+1;
    X10:=X10; y10:=y10+1;
    X11:=X11; y11:=y11+1;
    X12:=X12; y12:=y12+1;

    Canvas.Pen.Color:=clBlack;
    Canvas.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
Canvas.Ellipse(x3, y3, x4, y4);
Canvas.Rectangle(x5, y5, x6, y6);
Canvas.Ellipse(x7, y7, x8, y8);
Canvas.Moveto(x9,y9);
Canvas.Lineto(x10,y10);
Canvas.Lineto(x11,y11);
Canvas.Lineto(x12,y12);

  if y1>255 then
    Timer1.Enabled:=False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormPaint(Sender);
  Timer1Timer(Sender);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

По поводу вопроса - все работает. Можете установить точку останова в обеих процедурах и проверить.

Возможно вы судите работает или нет по результатам выполнения. Рисунок "стоит на месте" потому что выполняется сперва метод `FormPaint(Sender);`, который инициализирует параметры (устанавливает в начальные значения), а потом второй `Timer1Timer(Sender);`, который сдвигает рисунок.

Все будет рисоваться в автоматическом режиме если установить параметры:

```
Timer1.OnExecute := Timer1Timer;
Timer1.Enabled := True;
Timer1.Interval := 1000; // отрабатывать раз в секунду

Form1.OnPaint := FormPaint;
```